# Create a new set if two old sets have at least one common element?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `List<Set<String>>` like this:

```
[A, B]
[A, C]
[A, D]
[B, E]
```

If `set(i)` and `set(j)` have at least one elements in common, return a new `Set<String>`. For example, `[A, B]` and `[A, C]` would create `[A, B, C]` since they have a common element `A`, but `[A, C]` and `[B, E]` or `[A, D]` and `[B, E]` would create nothing since there are no common element.

For the `List<Set<String>>` above, the result would be:

```
[A, B, C]
[A, B, E]
[A, B, D]
[A, C, D]
```

How should I implement the algorithm as code, preferably by utilizing Java 8 Stream logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code do what you want:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final List<Set<String>> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    sets.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B")));
    sets.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "C")));
    sets.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "D")));
    sets.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("B", "E")));

    final List<Set<String>> sets2 = new ArrayList<>(sets.stream()
         .flatMap(set1 -> sets.stream()
            .filter(set2 -> containsElement(set1, set2) && !set1.equals(set2))
            .map(set2 -> mergeSet(set1, set2))
         )
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    System.out.println(sets2); // [[A, B, C], [A, B, D], [A, B, E], [A, C, D]]
}

public static <T> Set<T> mergeSet(final Set<T> a, final Set<T> b)
{
    return Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

public static boolean containsElement(final Set<String> set1, final Set<String> set2)
{
    return set1.stream().anyMatch(set2::contains);
}
```

Comment: I have a question - why does the keyword `final` needs to be used in method `mergeSet` and `containsElement`?

Comment: In fact, keyword `final` is about some optional code style. Some Java developers prefere to use this in any variables (if possible) to show that this variables is immutable and avoid some error when someone change this variables. Other developers said that keyword `final` just increase code source without real values. You just select what code style you prefere. If you want you can delete this keyboard.